# query json array with Oracle 12cR2 json features

Tags: json, oracle

I am using Oracle (12cR2) json but couldn't find a way to query arrays containing certain elements. Here is the test code:

```
CREATE TABLE json_array (
  id    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  array CLOB,
  CONSTRAINT json_array_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT json_array_chk_1 CHECK (array IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO json_array (id, array) VALUES (1, '{"a":[1, 3]}');
INSERT INTO json_array (id, array) VALUES (2, '{"a":[2, 4, 6]}');
INSERT INTO json_array (id, array) VALUES (3, '{"a":[1, 2, 5]}');
INSERT INTO json_array (id, array) VALUES (4, '{"a":[2, 5]}');
INSERT INTO json_array (id, array) VALUES (5, '{"a":[5]}');
INSERT INTO json_array (id, array) VALUES (6, '{"a":[5, 2]}');


COMMIT;
```

Create a domain index:

```
CREATE SEARCH INDEX idx_json_array ON json_array (array) FOR JSON;
```

I want to find all rows containing the array element 2 and 5, regardless their order in the array, i.e. the SQL should return the rows with id 3, 4, 6.

I tried many options:

SQL1:

```
select * from json_array j  -- return any arrays containing 2
where json_exists(j.array, '$?(@.a[0] == 2)');
```

==> return the rows containing 2: id = 2, 3, 4, 6

SQL2:

```
select * from json_array j  -- return arrays containing 2 at index 1
where json_exists(j.array, '$?(@.a[0] == 2  || @.a[0] == 5)');
```

==> return rows containing 2 or 5: id = 2, 4, 5, 6

SQL3:

```
select * from json_array j  -- return arrays containing 2 at index 1
where json_exists(j.array, '$?(@.a[0] == 2  && @.a[0] == 5)');
```

==> return no row

SQL4:

```
select * from json_array j  -- returns arrays containing 2 OR 5
where json_textcontains(j.array, '$.a', '[2,5]');
```

==> return rows containing 2 or 5: id = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

SQL5:

```
select * from json_array j  
where json_textcontains(j.array, '$.a', '{[2] & [5]}');
```

==> returns rows containing 2 AND 5, with 2 preceding 5

The only SQL that returns what I want is:
SQL6:

```
select * from json_array j
where json_textcontains(j.array, '$.a', '[2]') AND json_textcontains(j.array, '$.a', '[5]');
```

==> returns id = 3, 4, 6

But this solution can be very cumbersome when the number of elements increases.

Question: are there better option that SQL6 to return the same results?

Oracle version for testing 12c R2

Thanks in advance

James

Answer (score 0):

Does this help...

```
   SQL> with MY_TABLE as
  2  (
  3    select 1 as ID, '{"a":[1, 3]}' as ARRAY
  4      from DUAL
  5    union all
  6    select 2 as ID, '{"a":[2, 4, 6]}' as ARRAY
  7      from DUAL
  8    union all
  9    select 3 as ID, '{"a":[1, 2, 5]}' as ARRAY
 10      from DUAL
 11    union all
 12    select 4 as ID, '{"a":[2, 5]}' as ARRAY
 13      from DUAL
 14    union all
 15    select 5 as ID, '{"a":[5]}' as ARRAY
 16      from DUAL
 17    union all
 18    select 6 as ID, '{"a":[5, 2]}' as ARRAY
 19      from DUAL
 20  )
 21  select ID
 22    from MY_TABLE
 23   where json_exists(ARRAY,'$?(@.a == 2 && @.a == 5)')
 24  /

        ID
----------
         3
         4
         6

SQL>
```

Comment: This answers my question. thanks! (Sorry, I couldn't find a way to mark this answer as solution).